# GitLab CI/CD pull code from repository before building ASP.NET Core

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I have GitLab running on computer A, development environment (Visual studio Pro) on computer B and Windows Server on computer C.
I set up GitLab-Runner on computer C (Windows server). I also set up `.gitlab-ci.yml` file to perform build and run tests for ASP.NET Core application on every commit.

I don't know how can I get code on computer C (Windows server) so I can build it (`dotnet msbuild /p:Configuration=Release "%SOLUTION%"`). It bothers me that not a single example `.gitlab-ci.yml` I found on net, doesn't pull code form GitLab, before building application. Why?

Is this correct way to set-up CI/CD:

- User create pull request (a new branch is created)
- User writes code
- User commit code to branch from computer B.
- GitLab runner is started on computer C.
- It needs to pull code from current branch ([CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/variables/README.html))
- Build, test, deploy ...

Should I use common git command to get the code, or is this something GitLab runner already do? Where is the code?

Why no-one pull code from GitLab in `.gitlab-ci.yml`?

**Edited:**

I get error

> '"git"' is not recognized as an internal or external command

. Solution in my case was restart GitLab-Runner. [Source](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/issues/2743#note_47224585).

@MilanVidakovic explain that source is automatically downloaded (which I didn't know).
I just have one remaining problem of how to get correct path to my `.sln` file.
Here is my complete `.gitlab-ci.yml` file:

```
variables:
    SOLUTION: missing_path_to_solution           #TODO

before_script:
    - dotnet restore

stages:
    - build

build:
    stage: build
    script:
        - echo "Building %CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME% branch."
        - dotnet msbuild /p:Configuration=Release "%SOLUTION%"
    except:
        - tags
```

I need to set correct variable for `SOLUTION`. My dir (where GitLab-Runner is located) currently holds this folder/files:

```
- config.toml
- gitlab-runner.exe
- builds/
    - 7cab42e4/
        - 0/
            - web/                 # I think this is project group in GitLab
                - test/            # I think this is project name in GitLab
                    - .sln
                    - AND ALL OTHER PROJECT FILES      #Based on first look
                - testm.tmp
```

So, what are `7cab42e4`, `0`. Or better how to get correct path to my project structure? Is there any predefined variable?

**Edited2:**
Answer is [CI_PROJECT_DIR](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/variables/README.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure I follow completely.

On every commit, Gitlab runner is fetching your repository to *C:\gitlab-runner\builds..* on the local machine (Computer C), and builds/deploys or does whatever you've provided as an action for the stage.

Also, I don't see the need for building the source code again. If you're using Computer C for both runner and tests/acceptance, just let the runner do the building and add *Artifacts* item in your .gitlab-ci.yaml. Path defined in *artifacts* will retain your executables on Computer C, which you are then able to use for whatever purposes.

Hope it helps.

Edit after comment:

When you push to repository, Gitlab CI/CD automatically checks your root folder for **.gitlab-ci.yaml** file. If its there, the runner takes over, parses the file and starts executing jobs/stages.

As soon as the file itself is valid and contains proper jobs and stages, runner fetches the latest commit (automatically) and does whatever `script` item tells it to do.

To verify that everything works correctly, go to your `Gitlab -> CI / CD -> Pipelines`, and check out whats going on. You should see something like this: 
[image]

Maybe it would be best if you posted your .yaml file, there could be a number of reasons your runner is not picking up the code. For instance, maybe your .yaml tags are not matching what runner is created to pick up etc.

Comment: Thank you. I was afraid my post is unclear. Problem is that my GitLab-Runner does not fetch repository (current branch) on computer C. Or it does? I think not. I didn't give such order. Is this done automatically? Or I must use git `fetch` command?

Comment: Your edited answer already answer my question. I just have one problem, how to get path to project structure. I edited my question. Do you know how to get path to project structure?

Comment: Do you mean $CI_PROJECT_DIR from .yaml?

Comment: Yes, you beat me for 10 seconds.

Comment: Glad it helped.